# How does a permalink work?

Tags: python, django, permalinks

I have the following code in my models.py file and I'm wondering how it's used in the urls.py/rest of the django framework. What benefits does it give me?

```
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return('catalog_category',(), {'category_slug':self.slug})
```

How do I use this method?

Comment: Same thing a direct link to any page gives you: a direct link to that page.

Comment: You put it in the address bar of your browser.

Comment: how exactly? what am i putting in the address bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be used to return a url with your current object. If you have a model and url associated with your @models.permalink.

An example may be something like this
`{% for offer in offers %}`
`{{offer.title}}`
`{{offer.get_absolute_url}}`

In the urls.py file look at your related_names there should be one in related to .get_absolute_url function.

However, if you have return multiple urls using the same models, but are on different views .get_absolute_url can still be used. just in a different syntax such as `{% url url_related_name id=id %}` id would be in your instance you'd want `slug=offer.slug`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's used to avoid having to specify the URL scheme for the model in both the urls.py file, and the models.py file (Django is very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

Check out the [Django documentation on the @permalink decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator).